# 360* image stitching quality metric

Tags: image-processing, image-stitching, image-quality

I am working an 360 degree image stitching, I have taken few images and stitched using available software. My problem is I am not finding any parameter to evaluate the image stitching quality (in figures) performance. Can you suggest any image quality metric such as PSNR, MSE etc. to evaluate the stitched images.